# Is it possible to use a custom object with collaborative forecasts?

Tags: forecast, forecasts-collaborative

My organization has a custom object that has a child relationship with the opportunity object.  We use this object for monthly bookings.  Our organization has consumption based pricing.  We might have one opportunity with multiple bookings throughout the year.  We use these bookings for forecasting.

So far we have used custom reports to do all of our forecasting.  I looked at collaborative forecasting in the past but the functionality at the time didn't allow us to do what we need.  Since this seems to be a feature that Salesforce is building out I was wondering if may be what we want is available now.

Would it be possible to pull in individual bookings records into the forecast? Or is the forecast object limited to only information directly on the opportunity record.  We'd like to view the forecast per month using the bookings.

Comment: I know this isn't an "answer" per se, but I don't know any other way of "bumping" this discussion and have more or less the same question. Can anyone provide any input here?

Comment: @Joshua__c Once you have enough reputation you can offer a bounty on questions, which means assigning some of your rep as a bounty so others can claim it.

Comment: @Joshua_c - I would imagine your goal is a chimera; Collaborative Forecasts relies on Opportunity that happens to be one of the few standard objects that supports dated exchange rates - something custom objects don't support - and won't be - see [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpUrAAK) - and there are lots of other reasons I can imagine as well - known `closedate` field, use of `Stage`, known `Amount` field, known lookup to `Account`

Answer (score 0):

Custom object don't support forecasting. It is related to opportunity object and its fields.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE and thanks for your contribution. This answer can be improved by adding some quoted text from official Salesforce documentation and links to articles. Check [answer] for more details